# Is Maxwell-Bolzmann a Normal (Gauss) distribution or a Chi distribution?

Tags: statistical-mechanics

I was sure that the Maxwell-Bolzmann was a Normal distribution, but then I read that it was a Chi distribution [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%E2%80%93Boltzmann_distribution#Distribution_function).

Comment: Why don't you take a look at the relevant wikipedia articles? You're expected to do a reasonable amount of prior research before asking here...

Comment: @Danu I have done search on Google, but Wikipedia articles are obscure sometimes. Fortunately Sebastian Riese explained that to me! :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends on the parameter you consider.

The Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution (as the name is applied in the Wikipedia article you link) is the distribution of the particle's speed (absolute value of the velocity) in a gas and this is a chi distribution.

You probably were thinking of the distribution in terms of the vectorial velocity and then indeed it is a Gaussian (that is normal) distribution. This follows simply as classical particles follow the Boltzmann distribution $\propto e^{-\beta E}$ and $E = \frac 1 2 m \vec v^2$ for non-interacting particles in a gas.

Comment: i myself had this same doubt, thanks for the answer!